# moq a class that IS derived from the same interface as the one being moq'd

Tags: c#, class, interface, moq

I am new to the whole MOQ movement... which by the way is pretty cool ... and I am mocking all kinds of stuff now..

Anyway, I ran into this scenario and was wondering how to go about mocking it up.

I have an class that implements the interface that I want to mock:

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
    void doit();
}

public abstract class myBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable where TChannel : class
{
    protected TChannel Channel { get; private set; }

    // ICommunicationObject implementation not shown
}

public class myIIntClass : myBase<ImyInterface>, ImyInterface
{
    public myIIntClass()
    {
    }

    public void doit()
    {
         Channel.doit();
    }
}
```

I think my moq test doesn't mock anything... but I am unsure and hoping to get some insight on how to either write it correctly or refactor my class:

Here is my current MOQ test:

```
MyClass myClass = null;

Mock<ImyInterface> moq = new Mock<ImyInterface>();
moq.Setup(x => x.doit());

myClass = (MyClass)moq.Object;

myClass.doit();

moq.VerifyAll();
```

Thanks from one moqer to another... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like maybe you're missing the point of mocking here. You mock *dependencies* that exist in a unit of work you're testing. So, let's say I'm testing `doit` here in the concrete implementation of `MyClass`; I want to make sure it works right. Now, let's say that method has a dependency to another class; it calls a method on it that returns a boolean value. What I want to do is mock *that class* because I want to make sure that `MyClass.doit` behaves right when it returns `true` **and** when it returns `false`.

See, in the example above, what I've done is ensured that no other dependencies are affecting the code flow of `MyClass.doit`; I'm **forcing** `MyClass.doit` down a *very specific* path; I want to *test* that path.

The code you've created literally performs nothing because it just executes the mocked up method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mock/stub the unit under test. If you are testing the `doIt()`, you don't mock that, you mock its (or class) dependencies.